# Executable for iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, version, executable

I'm now working on a project with a drawer, and was asking is there is a way to send him a sort of executable of an app, so he could launch it from his iOS simulator and not pass in xcode interface ?

He would not have access to the source code, but could just run the app on his simulator.
As a .jar in java for example.

If it's possible, how to do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have a look at [Apple's doc regarding beta testing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)