# How to execute an arbitrary prebuilt binary on iOS Simulator?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, boost, ios-simulator

I have a prebuilt binary which was not built with xcode, therefore I don't have any .app or xctest or any other Xcode related build artifacts.
I'd like to run it however on the iOS Simulator. How can I do that?
I've already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008941/executable-for-ios-simulator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator/4894178#4894178). Didn't help.

Some more background to understand the question:
I am building one of the Boost C++ libraries for iOS and I want to execute it's own unit tests. Boost has a completely different build system (Bjam) and I customised it to use the proper iOS toolchain and clang link/compiler flags. 
I can't create an Xcode project for the whole Boost library, I already have a binary file (the unit test), which I just want to execute on the iOS Simulator.
(I could do the same task with Android really easily.)

Thanks,
Gabor

Comment: I think the first issue is that the app should be build for X86 and not ARM (iOS native). Then you will have to make some kind of .app file (it's actually a folder) and load that in the simulator

Comment: Hi, the prebuilt binaries was built for X86 (with -arch i386). So that is not the main issue here.

Answer (score -2):

After doing more research I've found the answer.
The answer in short is this: **It is not possible to do that.**

But I can have nasty and awful workarounds.
Here is what I did for a workaround in case of the boost log tests:
I've already had an Xcode project which was capable of executing some tests on iOS Simulator. So I hacked into the Xcode project all the source files of the boost log tests. This way recompiling them. Still, I don't know what could be the solution if the source files would not be available.